# Cakephp3 belongsToMany query not being generated correctly

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I think this is a simple belongsToMany situation, with the exception that the name of the relation is not the conjoined names of the entity tables. This is because the relationship is a very specific one. There is no extra data held in the join table, so the through option isn't necessary.

Entities:

```
table candidates {
  id int,
  <other fields>
}

table companies {
  id int,
  <other fields>
}
```

Join table (allows the candidate to blacklist a company):

```
table blacklists {
  id int,
  candidate_id int,
  company_id int
}
```

CandidatesTable.php:

```
 $this->belongsToMany('BlacklistedCompanies', [
            'className' => 'Companies',
            'joinTable' => 'blacklists',
            'foreignKey' => 'candidate_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'company_id'              
    ]);
```

Query in controller:

```
$bl = $this->Candidates->find("all")->where(["id" => 1])->contain("BlacklistedCompanies")->all();
```

When run, the following bad query is generated and throws an error (1054 Unknown Column) - see line with arrow at bottom:

```
SELECT 
    Blacklists.company_id AS `Blacklists__company_id`, 
    Blacklists.id AS `Blacklists__id`, 
    Blacklists.candidate_id AS `Blacklists__candidate_id`, 
    BlacklistedCompanies.id AS `BlacklistedCompanies__id`, 
    <remaining companies fields expunged>
FROM companies BlacklistedCompanies 
LEFT JOIN blacklists Blacklists ON 
    (BlacklistedCompanies.id = (Blacklists.company_id) 
      AND Blacklists.id = (Blacklists.blacklist_id)) <<-- ERROR!!
WHERE Blacklists.candidate_id in (:c0)
```

Why is CakePHP looking for blacklist_id??? It doesn't exist anywhere. Blacklist is a join table, not an entity with foreign keys referencing it anywhere!!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

OK I found the problem by stepping thru the core source code for a few hours (tracing the ORM logic is a real pain!!).

The other side of the relationship, Companies, had this relation from earlier in the development cycle:

```
    $this->belongsToMany('Blacklists', [
            'className' => 'Candidates',
            'joinTable' => 'Blacklists'
    ]);
```

I replaced it with the reversed relation from Candidates:

```
    $this->belongsToMany('BlacklistingCandidates', [
            'className' => 'Candidates',
            'joinTable' => 'Blacklists',
            'foreignKey' => 'company_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'candidate_id',                       
    ]);
```

And it seems to be working as expected. I suspect the lack of foreign key hints is the culprit.

So CakePHP3 lesson #1342: make sure your belongsToMany relationships are symmetrical!